# Out-Gridview - window doesn't closed when clicking on cancel - PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Need a little help to cancel the gridview when clicking on the cancel and if it possible to open a smaller window (there are many empty space) in addition sometimes the string is opened with ... and need to take the cursor to the right to see the full name.

The script reads the data from CSV and initialize the variables accordantly

```
$Versions = Get-Content "$SharedDriveFolderPath\Versions\dataSource.csv"
    $Versions = $Versions | ConvertFrom-CSV -Del ";"

    do { $VersionToUse = $Versions.Sheetcol | Out-Gridview -Title "Choose version from the list" -PassThru } while ($Versions.Sheetcol -notcontains $VersionToUse)

    $Versionlocationforpatches = ($Versions | Where-Object { $_.Sheetcol -eq $VersionToUse }).Versionlocationforpatches
    $Versionlocationforcabs = ($Versions | Where-Object { $_.Sheetcol -eq $VersionToUse }).Versionlocationforcabs
    $ReleaseVersion = ($Versions | Where-Object { $_.Sheetcol -eq $VersionToUse }).ReleaseVersion
    $Sourceversion = ($Versions | Where-Object { $_.Sheetcol -eq $VersionToUse }).Sourceversion
    $LinkForVersion = ($Versions | Where-Object { $_.Sheetcol -eq $VersionToUse }).LinkForVersion
    $VersionNumber = ($Versions | Where-Object { $_.Sheetcol -eq $VersionToUse }).VersionNumber
    $buildver = ($Versions | Where-Object { $_.Sheetcol -eq $VersionToUse }).buildver
    $PipelineID = ($Versions | Where-Object { $_.Sheetcol -eq $VersionToUse }).PipelineID
    $xmlFilePath = ($Versions | Where-Object { $_.Sheetcol -eq $VersionToUse }).xmlFilePath
    $Buildname = ($Versions | Where-Object { $_.Sheetcol -eq $VersionToUse }).Buildname
    $Sheetcol = ($Versions | Where-Object { $_.Sheetcol -eq $VersionToUse }).Sheetcol
    $QApath = ($Versions | Where-Object { $_.Sheetcol -eq $VersionToUse }).QApath
    $Weekendversion = ($Versions | Where-Object { $_.Sheetcol -eq $VersionToUse }).Weekendversion
    $BlockUpload = ($Versions | Where-Object { $_.Sheetcol -eq $VersionToUse }).BlockUpload
    $PrepareCI = ($Versions | Where-Object { $_.Sheetcol -eq $VersionToUse }).PrepareCI
```

This is a the output window:

[image]

This is how the csv looks like:
Each row in the window represent a row in the csv.

```
ReleaseVersion;Sourceversion;Versionlocationforpatches;Versionlocationforcabs;LinkForVersion;VersionNumber;buildver;PipelineID;xmlFilePath;Buildname;Sheetcol;QApath;Weekendversion;BlockUpload;PrepareCI
    8.5.34.31.6;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.5.34.31;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.5.34.31\Installer\Patches;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.5.34.31\Installer;\\global\builds\Releases\RingOne Builds\8.5 RingOne\8.5.34.31.6;8.5.34.31;8.5.34.31;18710;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.5.34.31\BuildDescription.xml;8.5.34.31.5;8.5.34 Side VIP CU4;\\global\QA\AgileTeam\Ziv\Builds\8.5.34.31-CU4;;;
    8.5.34.35.6;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.5.34.35;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.5.34.35\Installer\Patches;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.5.34.35\Installer;\\global\builds\Releases\RingOne Builds\8.5 RingOne\8.5.34.35.6;8.5.34.35_Federal;8.5.34.35;18713;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.5.34.35\BuildDescription.xml;Side VIP for 8.5.34.35_Federal;8.5.34.35 Side VIP Federal;\\global\QA\AgileTeam\Ziv\Builds\8.5.34.35_GA_Federal;;;
    8.6.22.607.40;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.6.22.607;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.6.22.607\Installer\Patches;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.6.22.607\Installer;\\global\builds\Releases\RingOne Builds\8.6 RingOne\8.6.22.607.40;8.6.22.607;8.6.22.607;26845;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.6.22.607\BuildDescription.xml;Side VIP for 8.6.22.607;8.6.22 Side VIP + CU6;\\global\QA\AgileTeam\Ziv\Builds\8.6.22.607;8.6.22.607.32;BlockUpload.txt;22212
    8.6.22.2000.38;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.6.22.2000;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.6.22.2000\Installer\Patches;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.6.22.2000\Installer;\\global\builds\Releases\RingOne Builds\8.6 RingOne\8.6.22.2000.38;8.6.22.2000_Federal;8.6.22.2000;27970;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.6.22.2000\BuildDescription.xml;Side VIP for 8.6.22.2000_Federal;8.6.22 Side VIP Federal;\\global\QA\AgileTeam\Ziv\Builds\8.6.22.2000_Federal;;BlockUpload_Federal.txt;22212
    8.6.32.236.4;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.6.32.236;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.6.32.236\Installer\Patches;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.6.32.236\Installer;\\global\builds\Releases\RingOne Builds\8.6 RingOne\8.6.32.236.4;8.6.32.236;8.6.32.236;26845;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.6.32.236\BuildDescription.xml;Side VIP for 8.6.32.236;8.6.32 Side VIP;\\global\QA\AgileTeam\Ziv\Builds\8.6.32.236;8.6.32.236.1;BlockUpload.txt;22212
    8.6.32.2002.5;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.6.32.2002;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.6.32.2002\Installer\Patches;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.6.32.2002\Installer;\\global\builds\Releases\RingOne Builds\8.6 RingOne\8.6.32.2002.5;8.6.32.2002;8.6.32.2002;27970;\\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile\SideVIP\Versions\8.6.32.2002\BuildDescription.xml;Side VIP for 8.6.32.2002;8.6.32 Side VIP Federal;\\global\QA\AgileTeam\Ziv\Builds\8.6.32.2002;8.6.32.2002.1;BlockUpload_Federal.txt;22212
```

Comment: `while ($Null -ne $VersionToUse -and $Versions.Sheetcol -notcontains $VersionToUse)`?

Comment: Thanks, now need to fix the window size issue

Comment: It would be far more flexible to make your own Forms GUI where you can control layout and content yourself.

Comment: In fact, why not just use Import-CSV to place the data into an object?

Comment: why do you repeat `$Versions | Where-Object { $_.Sheetcol -eq $VersionToUse }` instead of storing that into a variable for reuse?

Answer (score 0):

If you import the csv as an object and use forms, you can give yourself a lot more flexibility:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms -ErrorAction Stop

$Versions = Import-Csv -Path c:\temp\tempdata.csv -Delimiter ';'

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Select Version"
$form.Size = '250,220'
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$form.MaximizeBox = $false

# Listview box to display version
$DevListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$DevListBox.View = [System.Windows.Forms.View]::Details
$DevListBox.Location = '15,15'
$DevListBox.Size = '200,150'
$DevListBox.Columns.Add('SheetCol',180) | Out-Null
# Can add more columns as required
# $DevListBox.Columns.Add('PrepareCI',180) | Out-Null
$DevListBox.FullRowSelect = $true

$form.Controls.Add($DevListBox)

#PopulateListView
$Versions | ForEach-Object {
    $Entry = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($_.sheetcol) -ErrorAction Stop
    # You could add more fields as subitems if required, you need to add columns to the $DevListBox object if you want them displayed
    # $Entry.SubItems.Add($_.PrepareCI) | Out-Null
$DevListBox.Items.Add($Entry) | Out-Null
}

#Carry out actions when form closes
$form.Add_FormClosing({
    # Find the data corresponding to the selected item when the form closed 
    $SelectedItem = $Versions | Where-Object { $_.sheetcol -eq $DevListBox.SelectedItems[0].Text }
    # You could use this object directly, but assigning the values to your variables for direct comparison with your example
    $SelectedItem.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
        # Please read up about scopes - could use global here if needed
        Try {
            New-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value -Scope Script -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        Catch {
        }
    }
})
#

# Show form
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$form.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thank you @Scepticalist. look at my updated question regarding the csv file. I really don't understand how to use your solution

Comment: I don't think this solution will do the job for my project. how its working now: the user choose only the version and all the variables are filled accordantly, I don't need to displays many columns

Comment: The $Versions.Sheetcol should determine which row to work with

Comment: Can help to update you solution please?

Comment: If you need to use another column, just subsititute the value in the requisite line: `$SelectedItem = $Versions | Where-Object { $_.sheetcol -eq $DevListBox.SelectedItems[0].Text }`

Comment: Hi @Scepticalist when I run the script there is not text at all under the version 
I just can click on them but cannot see text or run

Comment: Did you tested it? , I really want to use it but its not working

Comment: Really? It;s telling you what it's doing. Amend this too: $Entry = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($_.sheetcol)

Comment: Really, I changed it to $_.sheetcol in both places and nothing 
Maybe you can try it in your machine please? 
Thank you @Scepticalist
Did you look at my csv format?

Comment: I copied one of the rows in my csv. maybe you can try to run it and see why all the rows in the form are empty please

Comment: In addition to the empty rows when closing the form there many errors

Comment: Edited the above code, with the corrections I advised you to make, and it works with your data

Comment: Hi @Scepicalist 
I ran the new code in my machine and still no text in the form. only can click on the 6 rows without see the version, even if I will see the text how you confirm your choose?
I want to add a picture with the form for you but don't know how

Comment: How it can work with the ; between the variables

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/yS61dkxupbmW6ZWK7

Comment: Added the full csv

Comment: If I will replace the $_sheetcol with a number I will be able to see the number
$Entry = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($_.sheetcol)
Something is wrong here

Comment: Please read up on the command - `Import-csv -Path filepath -Delimiter ';'`

Comment: Why you didn't wrote that I need the -Delimiter ';' 
I added this -Delimiter ';' and now I see the versions but how to continue with my choose? enter is not working 
Thanks

Comment: The code itself tells you that it picks your choice when you close the window - I suggest you learn for yourself how to change it in other ways, this is not a code writing service.